> Could not find method source() for arguments [src/main/resources/avro] on extension 'avro'
I'm trying to build my kafka consumer using a Avro Gradle plugin, but I get this error :

Could not find method source() for arguments [src/main/resources/avro] on extension 'avro' of type com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro.DefaultAvroExtension.

my build.gradle looks like this :
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id 'com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro' version '1.9.1'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'https://packages.confluent.io/maven'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:7.3.2'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20230227'

    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:7.3.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.1'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

avro {
    source("src/main/resources/avro")
    outputDir("src/main/java")
    stringType = "String"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += "src/main/java"
        }
    }
}

Any ideas please to help me solve this. Thanks in advance.
